# Render dynamic Font Awesome Icons

Tags: reactjs, icons, font-awesome

I need to use FontAwesome Icons Dynamically. The icon to be loaded will be held in a state whose value might change based on user interactions. Below is my code, When setting the icon statically it works(Line 2)however Line 3 the icon will not load.

```
const [selectedIcon, setSelectedIcon] = useState("faDragon");
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faDragon} color="white" size='6x'/>
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={selectedIcon} color="white" size='6x'/>
```